# How to fix unintentionally bandwidth sharing of 2 different fiber optic lines?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, isp, google-drive, fiber

I have 2 different fiber optic lines on 2 separated accounts, separate routers but of the exactly same model from the same ISP. They both have their own IP address. The problem is that when I upload files to Google Drive, using different google accounts on each line of course, the uploading bandwidth of these 2 lines got shared on each other. This decreases the speed by at least a half, sometimes even more. I'd like to know if there's a way to fix this from my end. Or what should I tell my ISP to do for me. Thanks

Comment: can you describe this network setup more clearly?  for example, are you uploading to google drive from one machine that is connected to both routers?  also, what do you mean when you say "the uploading bandwidth of these 2 lines got shared on each other" ?  How did you determine that?

Comment: Uploading from 2 machines, each to different router.  They both have their own IP address so I dont think google would see this bandwidth coming from one source. The determination is that when I stopped uploading from one machine, the other's speed doubled or tripled.

Comment: i would do a https://www.speedtest.net/ test on both machines at the same time, just take google drive out of the equation for now.  if that shows the same symptoms and you are certain that each device is properly connected to different routers, then it is entirely possible that your ISP has a slow or congested uplink in your neighborhood.     It is good to use speedtest.net when talking to your ISP so they don't point fingers at google.